# Lighthouse performance Optimization : Remove unused main.js and polyfills.js files build by es05 and es2015 plugins not working in angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, optimization, lighthouse

[Javascript files in dist folder generating after prod build [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l35S.png)

1. ng build --prod
2. ng serve ---prod
3. [After generating lighthouse report I am getting these unused js files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpDMM.png)

How can I remove these files to improve the performance?